# How to "handle" categorical variables, using flask?

Tags: python, html, machine-learning, flask, categorical-data

I have developed a ML model which would classify certain target variably Y based on the set of predictors (x1, x2, x3, etc). My task is to create some kind of a "calculator" in an HTML form where the user must fill in the data (x1, x2, x3, etc) and using that he would get a certain Y-result as an outcome. So, I used flask.

But the problem is that some of the predictors are of categorical types.
I used the `get_dummies` function to convert to build the ML random forest classifier. But, the problem is that I don't have a single clue how to "turn it back" for the user. I think he will be confused if he faces some set of 0 and 1 instead of a user-friendly HTML form.

The question is what do I need to write in HTML code so that my model worked in a meaningful logical way?
It also must be kept in mind that when doing "dummy encoding" there must be 1 reference group.

Any help would be appreciated :)

For example, I have the following varible in the dataframe "Other_technologies".
It has several options "Javascript", "SQL", "Kotlin", etc...

I have decoded them into the dummies, but...I don't know how to present it back for the user.

HTML FORM:

[image: HTML FORM]

Python:

[image: Python]

How would you advise me to hadle this variable?

Here you can see a piece of HTML code for this particular variable.

```
<br>
<label for="Other_technologies">Other technologies you know</label>
<select id="Other_technologies" name="Other_technologies">
<option value="0">C/C++</option>
<option value="1">Javascript</option>
<option value="2">Kotlin</option>
<option value="3">Python</option>
<option value="4">SQL</option>
</select>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert back to original value from dummies same way you did to get dummies from categories. Pandas provide **from_dummies** method that you can try. It will convert your 0's and 1's back to original values.

[Pandas from_dummies Ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html#pandas.from_dummies)